# Flink Python API Bug

Tags: python, apache-flink

i just tried out the flink python api. 
When i try:

```
env = get_environment()
```

I get:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/flink_data/output'
```

The error is because of a path handling in:

```
flink-staging/flink-language-binding/flink-python/src/main/python/org/apache/flink/languagebinding/api/python/flink/connection/Connection.py    line 44
```

Instead of using:

```
open(tempfile.gettempdir() + "/flink_data/output", "rb+")
```

One could create the mapping file with:

```
open(tempfile.gettempdir() + "/flinkoutput", "rb+")
```

The same applies for the mmap input file.
Would that be a fix?

Comment: If there's a bug in third-party software you should report it to the developers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to the issue tracker of related software

Comment: The JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2173 got resolved recently. If you are using Flink 0.10-SNAPSHOT you can try if your problem is resolved or not.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, cool will try soon :-)

Answer (score 3):

Please open a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK/
Python API is quite new and still in beta state. There is another related JIRA, too: see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2173

Thanks for reporting the problem.